# Why did Kichimura know Kaneki was going to mutate into Dragon, and why did he say he provoked it?

Tags: tokyo-ghoul

In the anime series of Tokyo Ghoul:re 2 , episode 12, Kichimura says he provoked the appearence of Dragon. In some former episode, when Kaneki mutated into Dragon , he was expecting it, as if he knew it was going to happen, he called it "dragon", and he said something like he expected dragon to destroy everything.

Why did Kichimura know Kaneki was going to mutate into Dragon, and why did he say he provoked it?

Comment: Ikr! I'm guessing he knew something about Rize's kagune that many others don't. Tbh the tokyou ghoul re 2 is going way to fast for me to keep up.

Comment: 'Why did Kichimura know Kaneki was going to mutate into Dragon and why did he say he provoked it?' This might not be clear in the anime but he was behind it all along. That was his plan from the start but how he was able to make Kaneki and Rize transform into a dragon was never fully explained in the manga.

Comment: @W.Are: You should leave that as an answer instead of as a a comment, and cite the source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kichimura is of the same family as Rize (the washu) but Kichimura is a demi human that got the Q surgery or the surgery like ken's from Kanou to have a kagune. he grew up where Arima and and Rize did, in the hands of the washu Rize was made to reproduce because they wanted a strong blood line and did not want to have kid with humans and have kids like Arima and Kichimura anymore so they made or cloned girls like Rize to bare the chair mans babys. Kichimura fell in love with Rize, as kids they played together and as he started to grow feelings he could not stand the fact that his disgusting old father would be with her and she would have to hold his child so he let her escape and she loved her freedom to much (binge eater). He then watched her for a long time until he pushed a bunch of falling pipes onto her and some school boy (ken), just to keep her closer to himself. It seemed as if Kichimura and Dr Kanou were working together with v as well. We all thought Rize died after that but she didn't and she was used to make Ken into a half ghoul first then Shiro and her sister then she was used to make army's. she was split up in little pieces everywhere but Kichimura knew he could bring Rise back to life through ken eating some more of rize, he would some how get rize back for himelf and the ccg would be taken care of by the dragon so he the leader of v and the last of the washu clan could have the only one he ever loved by his side finally. The 'dragon' seemed to have given life witch is hard to understand but there was also kanou who devoted his whole life to ghoul medical use on humans because he wanted to bring his mum back to life.

Comment: Very interesting insight, Could you add some sources to validate the answer? A manga source (like chapter and page or pic could suffice)

Comment: @Rumpelstiltskin Most of his answer are accurately taken from the manga although I agree that citing manga chapters is necessary. What I don't agree with his answer is 'he would some how get rize back for himelf and the ccg would be taken care of by the dragon so he the leader of v and the last of the washu clan could have the only one he ever loved by his side finally.' I'm trying to remember but I could not recall this being what he truly wanted. I'll try to reread and provide my own answer.

Comment: you should read the fight scene between Kaneki and Kichimura in the manga as i think thats probably got the most information about this question. it has been a while since i read the manga so my comment might of been more my opinion though what the words may have implied. translation can also be different and give you a different out look on the story depending on where you read it.

Comment: but seeing that humans are turning into ghouls there could be more of a plot twist that the Washu wanted to turn all of tokyo into ghouls and use rize as the weapon (the dragon)